# C Program to run Mac Application

Tags: c, macos

What should be the command used in C Program to run a Mac Application (.app) that is built from Xcode?

Is this the right way of doing it:

```
system(MyApp.app);
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: If you can use Core Foundation it is a C APIS and will give you a lot more robust functionality to locate and launch the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Mac often.  But I am almost positive that you can't just execute a .app file and have it run.  You need to do it with the open command:

```
system("open /path/to/MyApp.app");
```

Comment: The `-a` switch is required, and applications are directories (bundles) - not a single file.